# Python Dictionary with multiple keys that reference multiple values

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to make a randomizer for a game. It will take only the races (Listed as R#) each player (P#) is allowed to play and hand him two. There will be a lot of overlap on who can play what meaning I'll need to start from the Player with the fewest options and move up. I'm trying to utilize a Dictionary to put all the players in one variable.

```
Players = {
    "P1": ['R1','R2','R3','R4'],
    "P2": ['R1','R2','R5','R6'],
    "P3": ['R7','R1','R2','R8','R9','R10','R11'],
    "P4": ['R7','R3','R5','R4','R12','R13','R14','R10','R11'],
    "P5": ['R1','R2','R5','R15','R14','R10','R16','R17','R11'],
    "P6": ['R7','R1','R2','R3','R5','R4','R6','R13','R14','R10','R16','R17','R11'],
    "P7": ['R7','R1','R2','R3','R4','R6','R13','R15','R9','R16','R17','R11'],
    "P8": ['R7','R1','R2','R8','R3','R5','R4','R6','R12','R9','R14','R10','R17'],
}
```

This is my first trip into Dictionaries. Is there a better way to achieve this?

I tried to edit for clarity. Thanks for the attention and let me know if I can clear anything else up.

Comment: It all depends on how you'll use it, since you haven't showed us your access patterns - this approach is as good as any other!

Comment: Can you rephrase this question into generic languages? "It will take only the races you're allowed to play and hand you two." What? What is a race? _What_ will take and hand you things?

Comment: Also, what database are you using? Are you sure the most important question here is how you store this data _in memory_?

Comment: Everything listed as R is a race. I made them generic because it takes less space that way. Each P gets randomly selected two R's. import Random is the method for being able to randomize two things. 
What I want to achieve is the ability to add players, find the player with the least races available and randomly select two then move up the list.